# Array include by

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

I have two arrays of objects.

I am doing a comparison by id and availability

For example

```
   let newCars = []
   cars.forEach((car) => {        
      const element = _.find(this.state.cars, function(o) {
        return (o.id === car.id && (o.available < car.available))
      })
      if (element) {
        newCars.push(element)
      }    
    })
```

However, I would also like to include in the newCars array the elements that are not present in this.state.cars, but compared only by id.

For example, if cars has {id: 1, available: 4}, and this.state.cars has {id: 1, available: 5}, the would count as being present in both arrays and not be returned.

In summary, I need all the elements in cars for which car.available > car.available for the element with the same id in this.state.cars, plus, all the elements in cars which are not included in this.state.cars doing the comparison inclusion by id only.

Is this possible? (Uisng lodash or plain js)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find element, if not found add it, if found and has availability required also add it.

```js
   let newCars = []
   cars.forEach((car) => {        
      const element = _.find(this.state.cars, function(o) {
        return o.id === car.id
      })
      if (!element || element.available < car.available) {
        newCars.push(car)
      }    
    })
```